# UITableViewCell - Get UITextField values in dynamic tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

The problem is, most of the solutions I already found, involves using `self.myTableView.cellForRow(at: index) as!` method.
The problem is that if you have a big UITableView, the cell ends up being reused, and you lose the reference.

The other method involves using `textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)`,  but i don't know if is that the best elegant solution.

Heres some code that im using :

```
protocol TableViewCompatible {

    var reuseIdentifier: String { get }

    func cellForTableView(tableView: UITableView, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

}

class NameCellDTO: TableViewCompatible {

    var reuseIdentifier: String {
        return "NameCell"
    }

    var name: String?
    var placeHolder: String

    init(name: String? = nil, placeHolder: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.placeHolder = placeHolder
    }

    func cellForTableView(tableView: UITableView, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NameCell
        cell.configureWithDTO(self)
        return cell
    }
}
```

the DTO creation :

```
let nameCell = NameCellDTO(name: "Test", placeHolder: "attributes.user.first_name".localized())
```

I have an array with some `TableViewCompatible` DTO's
and the cellForRow :

```
func cellForRowAt(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let item = items.object(index: indexPath.row) else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    return item.cellForTableView(tableView: tableView, atIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: you need to keep data source for the app in some collection. so you can update cell when they are reused.

Comment: Are you using custom `UITableViewCell` subclass or just plain `UITableViewCell`

Comment: That makes sense to update the values inside the cell, but how I get the value inside the UITextField? I mean, after the user already changed the text? @rv7284

Comment: Could you perhaps post some code to show what you've tried so far? My instinct here is that this is something that should really relate to your data model: when the cell is edited the model should be updated and then you retrieve the data you need from there.

Comment: Custom ```UITableViewCell``` @Ladislav

Comment: So what is the problem with cell's reuse? If you use custom `UITableViewCell` subclass you have a way to get to UI Elements inside your custom cell...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try

```
var arr = [String](repeating: "", count: countOfRows)

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell =  ///

    cell.myTextF.delegate = self

    cell.myTextF.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.myTextF.text = arr[indexPath.row]
} 

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    arr[textField.tag] = textField.text!

}
```

Comment: Good idea, I end up adding a property value to my DTO :

```var value: String = ""```

And using a value Changed method, just to avoid subclassing NSObject

```cell.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)```

```    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        value = textField.text ?? ""
    }```, and them accessing the DTO to get the value